# Unique session id in python

Tags: python, session

How do I generate a unique session id in Python?

Comment: The correct answer for Python 3.6+ is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55661405

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [uuid library](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) like so:

```
import uuid
my_id = uuid.uuid1() # or uuid.uuid4()
```

Comment: @Gumbo: uuid will use the things like the mac address and uptime of your computer to come up with a random uuid, why is that not random?

Comment: uuid1(), uuid4() and even uuid5() are not good sessions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817882/unique-session-id-in-python/6092448#6092448 for a secure session ID example.

Comment: Wiki says that `Version 4 UUIDs use a scheme relying only on random numbers.`, how is it not good for a session token? uuid5 and uuid1 are not based on random numbers, but why is uuid4 bad then?

Comment: UUID doesn't use a crypto secure random number generator, and is therefore unsuitable for generating secure session ids. The correct answer for Python 3.6+ is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55661405

Answer (score 79):

**UPDATE: 2016-12-21**

A lot has happened in a the last ~5yrs.  `/dev/urandom` has been updated and is now considered a high-entropy source of randomness on modern Linux kernels and distributions.  In the last 6mo we've seen entropy starvation on a Linux 3.19 kernel using Ubuntu, so I don't think this issue is "resolved", but it's sufficiently difficult to end up with low-entropy randomness when asking for any amount of randomness from the OS.

---

I hate to say this, but none of the other solutions posted here are correct with regards to being a "secure session ID."

```
# pip install M2Crypto
import base64, M2Crypto
def generate_session_id(num_bytes = 16):
    return base64.b64encode(M2Crypto.m2.rand_bytes(num_bytes))
```

Neither `uuid()` or `os.urandom()` are good choices for generating session IDs. Both may generate **random** results, but random does not mean it is **secure** due to poor **entropy**. See "[How to Crack a Linear Congruential Generator](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf)" by Haldir or [NIST's resources on Random Number Generation](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html). If you still want to use a UUID, then use a UUID that was generated with a good initial random number:

```
import uuid, M2Crypto
uuid.UUID(bytes = M2Crypto.m2.rand_bytes(num_bytes)))
# UUID('5e85edc4-7078-d214-e773-f8caae16fe6c')
```

or:

```
# pip install pyOpenSSL
import uuid, OpenSSL
uuid.UUID(bytes = OpenSSL.rand.bytes(16))
# UUID('c9bf635f-b0cc-d278-a2c5-01eaae654461')
```

M2Crypto is best OpenSSL API in Python atm as pyOpenSSL appears to be maintained only to support legacy applications.

Comment: Those citations about UUID problems are helpful.  Thanks for posting that.  Question: what do you think is the best way to generate a session id?  Particularly with the faults you cite in UUID implementations, how would you do it differently?  I'm writing something like this right now and trying to come up with the best approach.  It's also got to be fault-tolerant - e.g., can't be dependent upon connection to a database server.

Comment: Any of the examples above would work. The key is making use of a good random number generator that is populated with "cryptographically sufficient entropy." Beyond aesthetics and the size of the representation, there is no difference between a encoding a sufficiently random value as a `Base64` string or a `UUID`, or even a hex encoded string. To each their own. I personally prefer base64 for size reasons.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems sound.  I wrote it this afternoon with

Comment: If we strip away all the fluff, what you're basically saying is that OpenSSL.rand.bytes(16) is secure but os.urandom(16) is not. According to the docs, os.urandom's purpose is to "return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use."  If generating a good session ID is not a "cryptographic use" for which os.urandom is suitable, then what is it meant for? Perhaps the correct solution is too simple for your taste, but that's Python for you.  Meaningless fluff doesn't make things more secure.

Comment: @SeunOsewa, you are correct about the docs and `os.urandom` being intended to be suitable for cryptographic use, unfortunately this isn't always the case, however. FreeBSD and OS-X have a good pool for urandom, Linux is hit or miss (though getting better). Being explicit is better than implicit. BTW, the reason I posted this was because I ran in to session ID conflict in a real world situation where session ID conflicts weren't checked and users saw each other's information. Cause? urandom wasn't being seeded properly. :-/ Reality bites sometimes.

Comment: @SeunOsewa You're correct, both OpenSSL and os.urandom use the same source of entropy (/dev/urandom) and have the same level of security.

Comment: A tentative -1. You claim without evidence that `os.urandom` is insufficiently random to be secure while OpenSSL (e.g. via M2Crypto) is better. Meanwhile @ramirami claims (also without evidence) that in fact both use the same underlying entropy source. I don't know who is right, but I'm downvoting anyway; I dislike FUD and the bold claim here (that `os.urandom` uses, or may use on some platforms, a worse source of entropy than OpenSSL, to the point that the former is cryptographically broken in contexts where the latter is secure) needs substantiating to be useful.

Comment: If you generate uuids with `id = uuid.UUID(bytes = OpenSSL.rand.bytes(16))`, keep in mind that you will have `id.variant == uuid.RESERVED_FUTURE`, so not `uuid.RFC_4122` and then `id.version` is `None`. This also means that 2 bits are changed to mark the variant, all others are just randoms. You might have collisions, whereas RFC 4122 based uuids are designed to prevent that.

Anyway, RFC 4122 states in section 6 (security): `Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used
   as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants
   access), for example.`

Comment: Did this get merged from another question? How on earth is security related to generating a unique session Id in pytest?  Note that uniqueness and security are very different topics.  Uniqueness is simply the chance of a **random** collision, security includes malicious actors deliberately trying to cause a collision or otherwise narrowing a search space to a manageable size.  The chances of a random collision even in python's uuid4() implementation remains vanishingly small, even if someone could guess it.

Answer (score 35):

Python 3.6 makes most other answers here a bit out of date. Versions including 3.6 and beyond include the `secrets` module, which is designed for precisely this purpose.

If you need to generate a cryptographically secure string for any purpose on the web, refer to that module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Example:

```
import secrets

def make_token():
    """
    Creates a cryptographically-secure, URL-safe string
    """
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
```

In use:

```
>>> make_token()
'B31YOaQpb8Hxnxv1DXG6nA'
```

Comment: Should I also append a HMAC to this token? To prevent people from hijacking sessions?

Answer (score 23):

```
import os, base64
def generate_session():
    return base64.b64encode(os.urandom(16))
```

Comment: I duno, but this appears to be a valid solution. However, I'd advise you to strip the trailing "==" and also include a time stamp for less chance of a collision.

Comment: The chance of a collision after 4 billion iterations is 1 in 8 billion.  If I want to reduce the chance of a collision further I can just increase the number of bits i.e. os.urandom(32).  And I don't understand what stripping the trailing "==" is supposed to achieve.

Comment: The trailing == can be removed to save space. All you have to do to decode it is to pad it back to the highest multiple of 4. Using urandom, it is possible to get very low entropy and end up with a duplicate. Using a timestamp is better.

Comment: Really? (I don't see how a 4-byte timestamp is better than an additional 4 bytes of randomness, but) if what you say about low entropy is true, then I would go for an auto-incrementing session_id since it's possible for many session requests to be issued roughly at the same time.  

Even in a low entropy situation, I don't except urandom to ever return a duplicate 32-byte string.  Pseudorandom algorithms may be attackable, but they don't return duplicate 32-byte sequences.

Comment: In a totally random system it is possible to return even a duplicate 32 byte string. In a low entropy system, this is even more likely. If you know that your computer can only spit out a session only so fast (ex. every 5 milliseconds) the minimum time it takes to execute that command, then this becomes a strict guarantee that you will never get a collision which is better than random.

Comment: I think it's ridiculous to complicate your session generator because of something that's "possible" but probably hasn't EVER happened before.  Like, say, our planet suddenly exploding.

Yes, it would be "safer" to never leave your house without a mobile lightning rod because it's "possible" that you'll be struck by lightning, but it's also very ridiculous.

Even if your computer can only spit out a session every 5ms, it's "possible" that two attempts to generate a session will be initiated concurrently on different processors in a multicore system. Do we need a processor id too?

Comment: I think it's best solution for my needs. I tried M2Crypto and PyCrypto but both present significant problems installing as well as running on windows.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as creating a random number.  Of course, you'd have to store your session IDs in a database or something and check each one you generate to make sure it's not a duplicate, but odds are it never will be if the numbers are large enough.

Comment: Exactly, Hence my solution:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817882/unique-session-id-in-python/818040#818040