# SecureRandom with NativePRNG vs SHA1PRNG

Tags: java, random, cryptography, prng

I need to generate cryptographically strong random numbers and byte arrays. For this purpose, I'm using Java's `SecureRandom` class. But I'm not sure to choose which PRNG algorithm in terms of their cryptographic strength.

Which of the following instances generates a more unpredictable numbers? Or are they equal?

```
SecureRandom nativePrng = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNG")
SecureRandom sha1Prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
```

Moreover, we are able to generate these instances with "SUN" provider (e.g. `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN")`). Do this make a difference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

TL;DR: Use [`new SecureRandom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#%3Cinit%3E()) when you're not sure and let the system figure it out. Possibly use [`SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong()) for long term key generation.

Do not expect a random number generator to generate a specific output sequence within a runtime application, not even if you seed it yourself.

---

With random number generators it is always hard to say which is best. Linux and most Unixes have a pretty well thought out random number generator, so it doesn't hurt to use `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, i.e. [`"NativePRNG"`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#securerandom-number-generation-algorithms). Problem with using `/dev/random` is that it blocks until enough entropy is available. So I would advice against it unless you've got some special requirements with regards to key generation.

---

`"SHA1PRNG"` uses a hash function and a counter, together with a seed. The algorithm is relatively simple, but it hasn't been described well. It is generally thought of to be secure. As it only seeds from one of the system generators during startup and therefore requires fewer calls to the kernel it is likely to be less resource intensive - on my system it runs about 9 times faster than the `"NativePRNG"` (which  is configured to use `/dev/urandom`).  Both seem to tax only one core of my dual core Ubuntu laptop (at a time, it frequently switched from one core to another, that's probably kernel scheduling that's which is to blame). If you need high performance, choose this one, especially if the `/dev/urandom` device is slow on the specific system configuration.

*Note that the `"SHA1PRNG"` present in the **retired** Apache Harmony implementation is different from the one in the SUN provider (used by Oracle in the standard Java SE implementation). The version within Jakarta was used in older versions of Android as well. Although I haven't been able to do a full review, it doesn't look to be very secure.*

*EDIT: and I wasn't half wrong about this, [SHA1PRNG has been shown not to be pseudo-random for versions < 4.2.2](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/JC2/exposes/ruhault.pdf) and more [here](http://blog.k3170makan.com/2013/08/more-details-on-android-jca-prng-flaw.html).*

Beware that `"SHA1PRNG"` is **not** an implementation requirement for Java SE. On most runtimes it will be present, but directly referencing it from code will make your code less portable.

---

Nowadays (Java 9 onwards) the OpenJDK and Oracle JDK also contain multiple implementations that are simply called `"DRBG"`. This implements a list of Dynamic Random Bit Generators specified by NIST in SP-108. These are not Java implementation requirements either. They could however be used if a FIPS compliant random number generator is required.

However, they do not change the recommendations here; if the developers thought that these were better than the default implementation then they would simply have made it the default. The contract of `SecureRandom` doesn't change: it is simply required to generate random numbers. Changes to the default algorithm have already been made in the past.

---

In general it's not a good idea to require a specific provider either. Specifying a provider may hurt interoperability; not every Java runtime may have access to the SUN provider for instance - Android certainly hasn't. It also makes your application less flexible at runtime, i.e. you cannot put a provider higher in the list and use that instead.

So only indicate a provider if you are dependent on one of the features that it supplies. For instance, you might want to specify a provider if you have a specific hardware device that generates the randoms, or a cryptographic library that has been FIPS certified. It's probably a good idea to make the algorithm/provider a configuration option for your application if you have to specify a provider.

The idea of not specifying a provider is also present in this [Android developer Security Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html).

---

So try and refrain from choosing any specific random generator. Instead, simply go for the empty argument constructor: [`new SecureRandom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#%3Cinit%3E()) and let the system choose the best random number generator. It is possible to use the new configurable [`SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong()) in Java 8 and higher if you have any specific requirements for e.g. long term key generation.

Don't cache instances of [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), just let them seed themselves initially and let the VM handle them. I did not see a noticeable difference in operation.

---

***When not to use `SecureRandom` at all:***

As a general warning I strongly advice against using the random number generator for anything other than random number generation. Even if you can seed it yourself and even if you choose Sun's SHA1PRNG, *don't count on being able to extract the same sequence of random numbers from the random number generator*. So do **not** use it for key derivation from passwords, to name one example.

If you do require a repeating sequence then use a stream cipher and use the seed information for the key and IV. Encrypt plaintext consisting of zeros to retrieve the key stream of pseudo random values. Alternatively you could use a extendable-output function (XOF) such as SHAKE128 or SHAKE256 (where available).

You may want to consider a different, non-secure random number generator instead of `SecureRandom` if the available RNG's deliver insufficient performance and if security is not an issue. No `SecureRandom` implementation will be as fast as non secure random number generators such as the Mersenne Twister algorithm or the algorithm implemented by the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. Those have been optimized for simplicity and speed rather than security.

It is possible to *extend the `SecureRandom` class* and insert a deterministic, seeded random implementation into a library call. That way the library retrieves a pseudo random number generator with well defined output. It should however be noted that the random number generator may be used in different ways by algorithms. E.g. RSA may switch to a better optimized way of finding primes and DES keys may be generated with adjusted or directly calculated parity bits.

Comment: Wouldn't it open a security hole if you just blindly trust any SecureRandom service picked up by the system?

Comment: No, not really. If the system cannot be trusted the random number generator is only a small part of the problem. Besides that, the other random number generators are usually seeded by a random number generator of the OS. So they are still dependent on the security of the system RNG. The only way around that is to have your own entropy source. Newer Intel chips have the RDRAND instruction, but in case of Java, you'll first need to go native before you can use it.

Comment: "Even if you can seed it yourself and even if you choose Sun's SHA1PRNG, don't count on being able to extract the same sequence of random numbers from the random number generator" What is the explanation for this? Doesn't this contradict the idea of what a PRNG should be?

Comment: @cygnusv Indeed. But that's what you get if you don't *define* the PRNG. The implementation of SUN has changed over time and the Apache Harmony (old Android one) one is incompatible and completely insecure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes answer is great, but I prefer to check myself sources, here's the JDK8 source code : [sun.security.provider.SecureRandom](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java), [sun.security.provider.NativePRNG](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java), [sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SeedGenerator.java)

Comment: "don't count on being able to extract the same sequence of random numbers from the random number generator. So do not use it for key derivation from passwords, to name one example."  why not?  You don't mention why the output (of the sha1prng) should be unstable.   The follow up question is inevitably, how do you derive keys from password (or other keys) in Java then?

Comment: @FrederickNord 1) the algorithm is unknown and may (and does) change between implementations and the seed may not be used as only input to the state, the algorithm may be pre-seeded by the operating system. 2) use PBKDF2, functionality is build into Java / JCE.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : Hi .. thanks for the example. In this context if u have a little time to check this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286343/java-securerandom-declaration-should-be-static-class-specific-or-can-be-instance

Comment: Could you remove the above comment? I read all questions about [tag:cryptography] and [tag:encryption]. Please simply use the right tags and don't directly ask persons for help on [so] or any other [se] site.

Answer (score 5):

As from a ref. [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java):

> Native PRNG implementation for Solaris/Linux. It interacts with
>   /dev/random and /dev/urandom, so it is only available if those files
>   are present. Otherwise, SHA1PRNG is used instead of this class.

The `SUN` provider might be used as default (mainly dependent on the order of the provider which is present).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

1. Prefer *NativePRNG* over *SHA1PRNG*
2. Configure JVM parameter to take entropy from /dev/urandom e.g.

   ```
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
   ```
3. Do not reseed frequently

Reason : Periodic *entroy injection* happens in *NativePRNG* , which adds more randomness compared to *SHA1PRNG*.

By providing entropy source from /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random, you are avoiding blocking call to RNG during entropy generation.

EDIT: Post java 8, *-Djava.security.egd* parameter is not required.

Comment: Do `NativePRNG` and `NativePRNGNonBlocking` exist on Windows? If so, what algorithm do they use? If not, what algorithm does `Windows-PRNG` use?

Comment: SHA1PRNG can be used by windows.

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: It answers why NativePRNG is preferred over SHA1. Second question is not relevant once we prefer NativePRNG

Comment: But I didn't ask the why of anything nor did I ask anything about `SHA1PRNG`. I want to know if `NativePRNG`/`NativePRNGNonBlocking` are valid names on Windows, what algorithms they use if they are valid, and what algorithm `Windows-PRNG` uses. Like, does `Windows-PRNG` use [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG))?

Comment: I did not see your comments in current questions. No mention of Windows OR NativePRNGBlocking. You can edit the question with above comments if you need accurate answer.  Refer to question content agian.

Comment: Just realized you and author are different.  Windows does not have NativePRNG. My comments in comment sections are related to original question ( part1 1 and 2 ). For your queries, you can post new question