# How to create Android Signing Certificate (keystore JKS file) programmatically instead of using Android Studio?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, jks, android-signing

I want to create jks file (keystore) file programmatically (some script on Java/Kotlin JVM) without using Android Studio. Is it possible?

[image]

I have a little code to create this file but how fill all the needed data to that key?

```
fun createJksFile() {
    val keyFilePassword = "test"
    val keyAlias = "test"
    val keyPassword = "test"
    val keyValidity = "100"
    val CertificateFirstandLastName = "Test"
    val CertificateOrganizationalUnit = "Test"
    val CertificateOrganization = "Test"
    val CertificateCityorLocality = "US"
    val CertificateStateorProvince = "US"
    val CertificateCountryCode = "US"

    val ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
    val password = keyFilePassword.toCharArray()
    ks.load(null, password)
    
    // TODO: how to set all needed data?

    FileOutputStream(File(projectDir, "_test_key.jks")).use { fos ->
        ks.store(fos, password)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to use this solution

```
val keystoreCommand = "keytool -genkey -noprompt \n" +
        "-alias ${keyStore.keyAlias} \n" +
        "-dname \"CN=${keyStore.certificateFirstandLastName}, OU=${keyStore.certificateOrganizationalUnit}, O=${keyStore.certificateOrganization}, L=${keyStore.certificateCityorLocality}, S=${keyStore.certificateStateorProvince}, C=${keyStore.certificateCountryCode}\" \n" +
        "-keystore \"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\keystore.jks\" \n" +
        "-storepass ${keyStore.keyFilePassword} \n" +
        "-keypass ${keyStore.keyPassword}"

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(keystoreCommand).apply {
    waitFor()
}
```

```
data class KeyStore(
    val keyFilePassword: String,
    val keyAlias: String,
    val keyPassword: String,
    val keyValidity: String,
    val certificateFirstandLastName: String,
    val certificateOrganizationalUnit: String,
    val certificateOrganization: String,
    val certificateCityorLocality: String,
    val certificateStateorProvince: String,
    val certificateCountryCode: String
)
```

Though we can do it without keytool but it's quite a lot of code to handle https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700785/7767664