# How to read file from docker container using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am new to this Dockerization part. I want to Dockerize the existing project. In this project we have multiple application.properties and Default.properties files which are not available in src/main/resources folder.
While creating image it is working fine , but while running image it is throwing a error message like below. I tried by adding COPY option as well for application.properties file.

Please find below docker file data and error message i am receiving and let me know if i want to add more details.

@UPdating question

As i am moving properties file from local to /myapp/ I want to update my script to read external prop file. Here i am using below code , can someone guide me how to read file from docker contains using Java.

```
File[] files = null;
            files = Paths.get(environment.getProperty("spring.config.location")).getParent().resolve(DATABASES).toFile()
                    .listFiles();
```

- List of files.

  ```
  /usr/app # ls
  env-prop services-testingtools.jar
  /usr/app # cd env-prop/

  /usr/app/env-prop # ls
  local
  /usr/app/env-prop # cd local/Jlo

  /usr/app/env-prop/local # ls
  application.properties databases
  /usr/app/env-prop/local # cd databases/

  /usr/app/env-prop/local/databases # ls
  DEFAULT.properties
  ```
- Docker file :

  ```
  FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
  EXPOSE 3434
  RUN mkdir /myapp
  ADD target/services-testingtools.jar /myapp/services-testingtools.jar
  ADD /env-prop/local/databases/DEFAULT.properties /myapp/DEFAULT.properties
  ADD /env-prop/local/application.properties /myapp/application.properties
  ENV spring.config.location=file:///myapp/DEFAULT-properties
  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --spring.config.location=file:///myapp/application-properties","-jar","/myapp/services-testingtools.jar"]
  ```
- Error message.

  ```
  2020-12-09 09:21:59.595 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'tokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenUtil'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenUtil': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.signing.key.secret' in value "${jwt.signing.key.secret}"
  2020-12-09 09:21:59.627  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
  2020-12-09 09:21:59.677  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
  2020-12-09 09:21:59.695  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
  2020-12-09 09:21:59.703 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
          at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
  ```

Comment: @TusharMahajan Yes it is working in STS.....issue with docker build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine with your configuration. The problem is that you are not setting the `spring.config.location` in a right way.

Please, try:

```yaml
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --spring.config.location=file:///myapp/application.properties","-jar","/myapp/services-testingtools.jar"]
```

Basically, remove the `classpath` prefix and adjust the `file` protocol URI.

Instead of the `ENTRYPOINT`, you can also define the config file location by defining the following environment variable in your `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
ENV SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///myapp/application.properties
```

You do not need any specific code to process the file, with these settings you are instructing Spring to apply that configuration.

Comment: "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"  I am not sure what is the exact use of this..i got this from outside and i am using this. Do i need to update anything here or it is predefined path to set up this ?

Comment: It has to do with random number generation, typically in old OSes. Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991966/what-java-security-egd-option-is-for) related SO question and answer.

Comment: Still i am getting same error. It seems still it is not able to identify the properties file. Update docker file code above. Do i need to update code to read file from config folder ? I provided the code which i am using to read pro files.

Comment: Please, instead of `file:///myapp/application-properties` use `file:///myapp/application.properties`, note the difference between the dash and the dot. Please, can you try again? Please, also use the `ENV` setting or the `--spring.config.location` in the `ENTRYPOINT`, not both. Also, the `ENV` setting should look like `ENV SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///myapp/application.properties`. Please, modify the Dockerfile as appropriate

Comment: We have two properties file..in DEFAULT properties file we are storing DB related information, So i have to use both properties files

Comment: I realized that. The second properties should be processed as a `PropertySource` in your configuration classes, something like `@PropertySource("file:///myapp/DEFAULT.properties")`

Comment: In this scenario i am using normal java code to read file from project directory...If i keep this in do i need to update the code for read data from docker container (file:///myapp/DEFAULT.properties)

Comment: No, you can use in your java code and process it as you need, you do not need Spring for that. Please, probably it will be better to use a `Properties` class.

Comment: If i proceed with same code we are getting error. mework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.hsbc.testingtools.TtServicesApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myapp/databases/DEFAULT.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Please, try `/myapp/DEFAULT.properties` instead of `/myapp/databases/DEFAULT.properties`, that is the location you are `ADD`ing it in your `Dockerfile`, or `ADD` the file in the right directory

Comment: No i updated that for default properties ADD /env-prop/local/databases/DEFAULT.properties /myapp/databases/DEFAULT.properties

Comment: Please, can you try `@PropertySource("file:/myapp/databases/DEFAULT.properties")`?

Comment: Tried this as well ...... getting nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myapp/databases/DEFAULT.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Please,can you verify if the file is actually in the indicated path? You can do it by running your container and perform ssh into it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: All file are available , I updated the question with the result. But it seems i need to update file read functionality. I provided the code with path, Please check the code for that also. For file read do i need to update the code, because it is searching for config file path and databases folder.

Comment: Issue resolved....I hardcoded the path of the Default properties file after copy into the docker container. Thanks for your support , thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much! Please if you need further help,do not hesitate to contact me