# How do I change the Java source for random data?

Tags: java, random, blocking

I'm trying to run code on a machine where `/dev/random` does not fill up quickly, and a java program I'm trying to use is hanging for lack of random numbers.

`/dev/urandom` produces "not as good" random numbers, but isn't blocking, and for this case I'd rather have less randomness and completing, than better randomness but never completing.

I tried passing this to java

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

But it didn't fix anything("/dev/urandom" has problems in places, whereas "/dev/./urandom" works everywhere, which is why I used that path).  Is there a way to do this?

I've now tried:

```
file:/dev/./urandom
file://dev/./urandom
file:///dev/./urandom
file:/dev/urandom
file://dev/urandom
file:///dev/urandom
```

none have worked

Comment: See [myths about `/dev/urandom`](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Comment: It might be better to look at ways of setting your system up to fill random quicker. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89/feeding-dev-random-entropy-pool gives some examples on how to do this

Comment: @DevWithZachary unfortunately I don't control the system, so that's not one of my options.  All the other machines on the cluster fill up their random just fine (yes, i have a bug report in)

Comment: Java already uses /dev/urandom for the `nextBytes()` call. Perhaps you can show the code that's causing your problems, the version of Java you're using, and the platform it's running on.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I can't. the code is in GATK 3.8.  Java *, u202, teh last free Oracle version

Comment: I assume Java * should be Java 8, the * being above the 8 key, at least on my keyboard.

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell from reading the source code for NativePRNG, `getSeed()` may use /dev/random but `nextBytes()` uses /dev/urandom. So use `nextBytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

`fileurl` do require 2-3 forward slashes (according to [RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-5)):

```
-Djava.security.egd=file://dev/./urandom
-Djava.security.egd=file://dev/urandom
```

- That system may only support the `NativePRNG`, but not the `SHA1PRNG` algorithm. Here it's explained: [What java.security.egd option is for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991966/what-java-security-egd-option-is-for) To see what is available: `cat /dev/./urandom` and `cat /dev/urandom`. [manpages](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom) state, that one can simply create the devices, in case they don't exist.
- There still is the possibility, that Java code might do blocking I/O.
- With containers this can also lead to performance issues:

> The `/dev/random` device is a scarce shared system resource that Linux Container tenants likely have not realised they are sharing. When they all try to use it at the same time they are effectively causing a denial of service on each other.

Comment: Unfortunately neither file://dev/./urandom nor file:///dev/./urandom work