# SecureRandom Sha1Prng throws Unsupported Operation Exception

Tags: java, kotlin, secure-random

I am using java's Secure Random in a kotlin application. When I instantiate it with "DRBG" and seed:

```
     val rng : SecureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("DRBG")
     rng.reseed()
```

everything works fine. However when I do the same with "SHA1PRNG":

```
     val rng : SecureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
     rng.reseed()
```

I get an unsupported operation exception. How can I fix this? I am aware that I do not have to seed after constructing, but I do need to reseed later, and I get the same error.

Comment: Might want to check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27638413/49746

Comment: @Todd the issue is that I originally called the constructor directly with no parameter - `val rng = new SecureRandom()`. this worked on my machine but then gave the unsupported operation exception detailed in my post.